# How to mock browser specific property `window.location.origin` with AVA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsdom, ava

### Context

I have Frontend React+Webpack app consuming backend APIs.
My Webpack setup depends on `window.location.origin` the property, for setting up and deployment processes.
Currently, I'm using Karma testrunner and am trying to replace it with AVA testrunner.

I'm trying to apply AVA with this [single entry setup for webpack](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/precompiling-with-webpack.md#single-entry-file) recipe 
I'm also applying the [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) as dom emulator for the node.

### Problem

Some of the tests being bundled, use the `location.origin` property.
Which throws an error during running `webpack && ava` script:

```
var apiUrl = process.env.API_URL && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? process.env.API_URL : location.origin;
ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

Karma runs on browser engine and reproduces the value of `window.location.origin` dynamically.
With AVA is different. It doesn't run browser of any kind when running test. I can only (as far as I know) "emulate" the browser environment with `jsdom`, and that is what I am trying to do.
However specific `location.origin` property is not supported by `jsdom`
[Issue Link](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1789)

### The Question

Could anyone track me to the solution to reproduce the `window.location.origin` dynamically (environmentally aware) for AVA?
I know that I can put it in constant and store it in `.env` per each environment.
But this is another maintenance task I would like to mitigate.

Comment: You could of course setup a global variable that is created before your tests start. But, why not use `typeof location !== 'undefined' && location.origin !== undefined ? location.origin : 'fallback-api-url'`? I assume you only set this once. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not setting it up anywhere @AluanHaddad. Karma runs browser during tests and the value is get from the real browser env. And this is as I want it to be. AVA doesn't run browser for tests, so the value is undefined. I wonder if there is any other way to get the real value of this browser property with AVA. Instead of setting it up in the code.

Comment: you could have a function that fetches the value of window.location.origin in your production code and then mock the return value of this function in your tests

Comment: @MiloszFrejnik what I mean is, do you need to associate the value with jsdom or can you just use an arbitrary value like you do when `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`?